# Modal ConfirmDialog over modal Dialog -> everything is blocked

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a modal ConfirmDialog that is shown over a modal Dialog using PrimeFaces 3.0.1. 
If the ConfirmDialog is opend, the whole page becomes locked, inclusive the ConfirmDialog itself... rien ne va plus

I found a Bugreport for Primefaces that sounds similar http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=576 but since the bug is related to a Layout-Component this does not really apply in my case.

Is there a workaround or something?

Thanks!!!

Comment: what version of PF do u use? cause it was fixed in 3.0 http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2575

Comment: I'am using 3.0.1... doesn't seem to be fixed yet

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use the `appendToBody="true"` attribute of the `p:dialog` tag to resolve this.

From PrimeFaces 5 on the attribute has changed. If you are using 5+ use  `appendTo="@(body)"` instead, see the migration guide: [migration guide](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)

(It would have been helpful to know your Primefaces version)

Comment: Thanks! Adding appendToBody="true" to p:confirmDialog is the solution in my case!

Comment: This (`appendToBody="true"`) solved the issue in my (PrimeFaces 3.2) application as well, both for confirmDialogs that only generate AJAX requests and those that refresh the whole page.

Comment: @daVe: the attribute is different in PrimeFaces 5, see the migration guide: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide . In short: use appendTo="@(body)" in PrimeFaces 5

Answer (score 5):

Use appendTo="@(body)" in the tag  it works for me

Comment: appendToBody="true" doesnt work for me.But it worked properly.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I need a submit-button in the Dialog I unfortunatly had to search for a different solution then appendToBody="true". For everybody who faces the same problem, here comes the solution:

If you want to to the following:

```
<p:dialog modal="true">
    <h:form>
        ...
        <p:confirmDialog>
            <p:commandButton action="#{transportBean.execute}" type="submit" .../>
        </p:confirmDialog>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog
```

This will lead into a completly blocked page. Pull the Form Element two elements higher and it will work:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog modal="true">        
        ...
        <p:confirmDialog>
            <p:commandButton action="#{transportBean.execute}" type="submit" .../>
        </p:confirmDialog>
        ...        
    </p:dialog
</h:form>
```